# Prefetch resources for async routes

Tags: react-router

Is there a way to prefetch or preload async routes? I'm exploring how to do this right now with RR2/3. The basic idea is I code split on every route but I'd like to be able to cache bundles for connected pages in a service worker before visiting that page. So what I'd like to do is have a custom `<Link>` that every time it's rendered, it tries to cache the resources of the page it's linked to. This would make page transitions considerably faster. What I don't know is if there's a way to emulate navigating to a route so that the resources will be fetched. Is there an API for this or some sort of tricky way to do this someone can think of?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up. It's a component that wraps the React Router Link component and in `componentDidMount` (so only runs on the client not the server) check if in production (no need to run this during development) and if this is a browser that *doesn't* support Service Workers (this check is specific to my use case). Then manually match against the location and call any async `getComponent` functions.

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'react-router/lib/Link'

class GatsbyLink extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    // Only enable prefetching of Link resources in production and for browsers that
    // don't support service workers *cough* Safari/IE *cough*.
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && !('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
      const routes = require('my-routes')
      const { createMemoryHistory } = require('history')
      const matchRoutes = require('react-router/lib/matchRoutes')
      const getComponents = require('react-router/lib/getComponents')

      const createLocation = createMemoryHistory().createLocation

      if (typeof routes !== 'undefined') {
        matchRoutes([routes], createLocation(this.props.to), (error, nextState) => {
          getComponents(nextState, () => console.log('loaded bundle(s) for ' + this.props.to))
        })
      }
    }
  }

  render () {
    return <Link {...this.props} />
  }
}

module.exports = GatsbyLink
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a `require.ensure...` section in a timeout when the Link is mounted. That should require the code split and load it up async. The timeout will ensure it get's loaded in a separate file.

I would recommend using RR4 for code splitting as I found in RR3 the async required routes get re-included and re-rendered if a child route changes. In my case, I had the componentWillMount of my routes being fired for any child route changes. e.g. Navigating from `/agent/step-1` to `/agent/step-2` will cause the Component for `/agent` to be unmounted and re-mounted.

Comment: I already have require.ensure stuff setup in my routes definition so don't want to recreate that — just make sure each level of the matched route gets its resources fetched.